# Node.js and SQLite save multiply rows

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am searching since few hours now and i dont know if my syntax is always wrong or if in SQLlite there is not such a multi insert statement. So what i want to do is just insert 100 or 1000 user at same time into a table with just one request.

The following code is saveing now just one user into the table, can somebody show me a example how it must look when i want to save 100 users at same time into the table

```
let sql = 'INSERT INTO users';
       sql += '(eins';
       sql += ', zwei';
       sql += ', drei';
       sql += ', vier';
       sql += ', fuenf';
       sql += ', sechs';
       sql += ', sieben';
       sql += ', acht';
       sql += ', neun)';
       sql += 'VALUES';
       sql += "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    let objectary = [];
    for(let a=0; a<9; a++)
        objectary[a] = a;
    

    db.run(sql, objectary, function(err)
    {
      if(err)
      {
        res.status(200).json(err.message);
        return console.error(err.message);
      }

      if(this.changes > 0)res.status(200).json(1);
      else res.status(200).json("no changes saved");
    });
```

i think the objectary just need to be write in another format/way to make it work or? so i want to save with this one request 100 users and now it is just saveing one user so one entry

so i have try a few different syntax i have try to build json format but whatever i try there is always a error from sqlite, so please just show me somebody how i can write this statement correctly

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as MYSQL the rows are delimited by a ","
so your statement would need to look like this

```
INSERT INTO users(columns...) 
VALUES
(values...),
(values...),
(values...),
...;
```

Comment: yes that have work, i wonder why sometimes the new style of codeing looks always so complicate, you dont know where to serach errors, the old style have work, just adding the values to the query string.